# How to replace a single quote to double quote in Python csv writer?

Tags: python, regex, csv

I've been trying to output a csv file using python. It's working fine without quotation marks and numbers. Example:

code:

```
for n in G:
    centrality = nx.degree_centrality(G)
    betweeness = nx.betweenness_centrality(G)
    edges = nx.edges(G, n)
    csv_out.writerow([n, str(edges).replace("'",""), round(centrality[n],2), round(betweeness[n],2)])
```

output:

```
24,"[(24, 31), (24, 64)]",0.02,0.04
25,"[(25, 77)]",0.01,0.0
26,"[(26, 49)]",0.01,0.0
27,"[(27, 75), (27, 79)]",0.02,0.02
20,"[(20, 9), (20, 84), (20, 40)]",0.03,0.03
21,"[(21, 77), (21, 64)]",0.02,0.02
```

I need to be able to input also string data. Example:

```
Automation Specialist I,"[(Automation Specialist I, Data Coordiator)]",0.01,0.0
Community Outreach Specialist,"[(Community Outreach Specialist, Librarian)]",0.01,0.0
Research Assistant III,"[(Research Assistant III, Senior Quality Engineer)]",0.01,0.0
Cost Accountant,"[(Cost Accountant, Structural Engineer)]",0.01,0.0
Data Coordiator,"[(Data Coordiator, Technical Writer), (Data Coordiator, Automation Specialist I)]",0.02,0.01
```

However I need a quoted value in order to process it on the front-end. Like this:

```
Automation Specialist I,"[("Automation Specialist I", "Data Coordiator")]",0.01,0.0
Community Outreach Specialist,"[("Community Outreach Specialist", "Librarian")]",0.01,0.0
Research Assistant III,"[("Research Assistant III", "Senior Quality Engineer")]",0.01,0.0
Cost Accountant,"[("Cost Accountant", "Structural Engineer")]",0.01,0.0
Data Coordiator,"[("Data Coordiator", "Technical Writer"), ("Data Coordiator", "Automation Specialist I")]",0.02,0.01
```

So I used the code below:

```
csv_out.writerow([n, str(edges).replace("'",'"'), round(centrality[n],2), round(betweeness[n],2)])
```

However, the result is this:

for numbers:

```
24,"[(""24"", ""31""), (""24"", ""64"")]",0.02,0.04
25,"[(""25"", ""77"")]",0.01,0.0
26,"[(""26"", ""49"")]",0.01,0.0
```

for string:

```
Automation Specialist I,"[(""Automation Specialist I"", ""Data Coordiator"")]",0.01,0.0
Community Outreach Specialist,"[(""Community Outreach Specialist"", ""Librarian")]"",0.01,0.0
```

I've also tried to replace the out quotation mark (outside of the list) with an apostrophe, without success. I tried also to use the code below, but it gives the same result as above.

```
str(edges).replace("'",'"').replace('""','"')
```

What should I do in order to get the result I want?
I plan to filter the type of the input afterwards in order to apply the technique only if is string. Because if it's a number, the ideal output is the first example. When I use the last one, my front-end code process text and numbers. But when I use the first example, it doesn't works for text, only for numbers.

Can you help me, please? 
How can I replace the apostrophe to quotation mark?
Thank you very much.

Comment: [`quotechar` option](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv.Dialect.quotechar) should give you what you want. You shouldn't try to modify a CSV file yourself - the format looks simple, but it is actually rather tricky to do correctly. (The definition of `csv_out` object is relevant, getting it into the question would have been good for you.)

Comment: can you give us what the line looks like if you do not try and replace anything? I would like to see what the unformatted text looks like ... Also I am confused at this str(edges).replace("'",'"').replace('""','"') Why are you doing " ' " as well as ' " ' and ' "" ' .... why are you using different formats?

Comment: What is wrong with writing "[(""Automation Specialist I"", ""Data Coordinator"")]"?  The quote character are supposed to be doubled in the raw CSV format. Reading this CSV with a decent CSV parser (like Excel) will result in the string [("Automation Specialist I", "Data Coordinator")], which seems all right for your front-end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've ended up using the code below:

```
if(is_number(n) == True):
    edges_w = str(edges).replace("'","")
else:
    edges_w = str(edges).replace("'",'"')
```

I've used a function to check if it's a number and then replaced the str according to this function return value. I've considered @Stein comments to use this solution.

Comment: what if there is `'` quote in the middle of the string like apostrophe.

Answer (score 1):

Try to escape the double quotes with a backslash. e.g.

```
str(edges).replace("'","\"")
```

Comment: This does exactly the same as what Jaqueline did, it's just a matter of style, and python seems to prefer Jaqueline's style over yours: enter `"\""`on the python prompt, and python echoes it as `'"''`